# Woocommerce i am not able to show featured products on search page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront, woocommerce-theming

In `storefront` theme, for no result in `search page`, I would like to show `featured products` in that view.

So in `/storefront/woocommerce/loop/no-product-found.php`, i've added this code:

```
<div class="site-main">
  

<?php echo do_shortcode('[products per_page="10" columns="3"]')?>
</div>
```

So when i search for something like "shoes",I was hoping wordpress to show no results and then goes on showing the featured products. However, I'm not able to show the featured products.

When I check the query, its partly due to the page is in search where there is a query searching for the product name which is "shoes".

Is there a way to exclude that in any queries for search page? If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcode you tried to use is incorrect.

The shortcode for `featured products` is:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[featured_products limit="3"]');
```

Note: you could also pass it a limit.

> [`woocommerce shortcodes`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

---

**Other related shortcodes:**

For products on sale:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[sale_products]');
```

For popular products:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products]');
```

For top rated products:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[top_rated_products]');
```

For recent products:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[recent_products]');
```

---

Since you're using `storefront` theme, it has a `404` page which shows `featured products` and `Popular Products` etc. by default! You don't have to change/modify any of its templates. However, if you're overridding `storefront` with woocommerce templates then you could go ahead and manipulate any template you want using the shortcodes i just gave you!